# Trying to find the employee who placed the highest bid out of 5 employees

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

The point of the assignment is to assign all 5 people names and the number of times they bid(must be below or at zero). Then I will need to take those names and numbers and store them so they can then be displayed as the employee who had the highest bid and how much he bidded.
Ex: Jason had the highest bid of 63.

**This is the code I had tried, everything works up until it’s comparing the largest bid and it chooses my first bidder every time. I’m still new to this so I don’t know all the terms and specifics so talk to me like a child.
Code in C#:**

```
using System;
class TopSeller
{
    private static void 

Main(string[] args)
    {
        string employee;
        int widgetsSold;

        //Employee #1

        Console.WriteLine("Hello,     Can you please enter your name: ");
         employee =Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of widgets sold: ");
        widgetsSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(widgetsSold > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number has to be at or below 100. Re-enter Widgets sold: ");
            widgetsSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //Employee #2
        int widgetsSold2;
        String employee2;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Can you please enter your name: ");
        employee2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of widgets sold: ");
        widgetsSold2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (widgetsSold2 > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number has to be at or below 100. Re-enter Widgets sold: ");
            widgetsSold2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //Employee #3
        String employee3;
        int widgetsSold3;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Can you please enter your name: ");
        employee3 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of widgets sold: ");
        widgetsSold3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (widgetsSold3 > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number has to be at or below 100. Re-enter Widgets sold: ");
            widgetsSold3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //Employee #4
        int widgetsSold4;
        String employee4;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Can you please enter your name: ");
        employee4 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of widgets sold: ");
        widgetsSold4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (widgetsSold4 > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number has to be at or below 100. Re-enter Widgets sold: ");
            widgetsSold4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //Employee #5
        int widgetsSold5;
        String employee5;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Can you please enter your name: ");
        employee5 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of widgets sold: ");
        widgetsSold5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (widgetsSold5 > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number has to be at or below 100. Re-enter Widgets sold: ");
            widgetsSold5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //top seller and largest bid
        String TopSeller;
        int LargestBid = 0;


        //Comparison
        if (widgetsSold > widgetsSold5)
        {
            TopSeller = employee;
            LargestBid = widgetsSold;
        }
        else if(widgetsSold < widgetsSold5)
        {
                TopSeller = employee5;
                LargestBid = widgetsSold5;
        }
        else if(widgetsSold4 > widgetsSold5)
        {
            TopSeller = employee4;
            LargestBid = widgetsSold4;
        }
        else if(widgetsSold3 > widgetsSold4)
        {
            TopSeller = employee3;
            LargestBid = widgetsSold3;
        }
        else if(widgetsSold2 > widgetsSold3)
        {
            TopSeller = employee2;
            LargestBid = widgetsSold2;
        }
        else if(widgetsSold > widgetsSold2)
        {
            TopSeller = employee;
            LargestBid = widgetsSold;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(TopSeller + " had the largest sell of: " + LargestBid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have loops been discussed already?

Comment: By using if else, you can't compare all bids elements against each other without being so convoluted.  A series of ifs is enough, or, if you're already taught about arrays, a for/foreach loop enumerating an array is a much better choice.

Comment: And classes? Did you hear about classes? Because it would be much easier if you collected user and bid info bundled in a class, of which you then can find the max bid.

Comment: Store response for each employee in database and then compare that data to find topseller/largest bid

Answer (score 0):

So first think about holding related data together in a object. There are a few different types of object that we could use (take a look at records and structs if you're interested in this), but for simplicity let's build a `Bid` class.

```
public class Bid {
    public string EmployeeName { get; }
    public int WidgetsSold { get; }

    public Bid(string employeeName, int widgetsSold)
    {
        EmployeeName = employeeName;
        WidgetsSold = widgetsSold;
    }
}
```

Above we're creating a `Bid` object to keep our data together. This object has a couple of properties, I've marked these as get only as once a bid has been created, we don't want to change it. Then there's a constructor that takes the name and number of widgets and stores them to these properties.

Now we can create several of these bid classes and compare them to each other easily. We're going to build up a list of these bids and then get the highest one from there. The data capture can be split out to some private methods so that we're keeping all the input validation for each field together. We'll also put the logic for creating the bids in a loop so that we're not repeating code and can easily extend to a different number of bids to be captured.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class TopSeller
{
    // Defines the number of times to ask for bids
    public const int NumberOfBids = 5;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create the list that will hold our bids
        var bidList = new List<Bid>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfBids; i++)
        {
            
            var employeeName = ReadEmployeeName();
        
            var widgetsSold = ReadNumberOfWidgets();

            // Create a new Bid and add it to our list.
            bidList.Add(new Bid(employeeName, widgetsSold));
        }

        // Put the bids in order of largest number of widgets sold to smallest, and select the first one
        var maxBid = bidList.OrderByDescending(bid => bid.WidgetsSold).First();

        Console.WriteLine($"{maxBid.EmployeeName} had the max bid of {maxBid.WidgetsSold}");
    }

    private static string ReadEmployeeName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, can you please enter your name: ");

        while (true) // We want to loop forever until someone enters a valid name
        {
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name must not be empty, please try again");
            }
            else
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int ReadNumberOfWidgets()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of widgets sold: ");

        while (true) // We want to loop forever until someone enters a valid number of widgets
        {
            var numberOfWidgetsString = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberOfWidgetsString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number of widgets must not be empty, please try again");
            }
            else
            {
                var success = int.TryParse(numberOfWidgetsString, out var numberOfWidgets);

                if (!success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number");
                }
                else if (numberOfWidgets < 0 || numberOfWidgets > 100)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number of widgets must be between 0 and 100");
                }
                else
                {
                    return numberOfWidgets;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```